# Interpretation of vector error correction model in R

Tags: r, interpretation, vector-error-correction-model

I estimated a VECM using the following code:

```
mysample<-Canada[,c("e", "prod", "rw", "U")]
myvecm<-ca.jo(mysample,ecdet="const",type="eigen",K=2,spec="longrun")
myvecm.ols<-cajools(myvecm)
myvecm
```

I got the results below:

```
################################################### 
# Johansen-Procedure Unit Root / Cointegration Test # 
##################################################### 

The value of the test statistic is: 6.8796 10.512 24.9145 63.5378 

> myvecm.ols

Call:
lm(formula = substitute(form1), data = data.mat)

Coefficients:
          e.d         prod.d      rw.d        U.d       
e.dl1        0.63782    -0.17277    -0.26883    -0.58076
prod.dl1     0.16727     0.15043    -0.08107    -0.07812
rw.dl1      -0.06312     0.05130    -0.10452     0.01866
U.dl1        0.26558    -0.47850     0.01213    -0.38107
e.l2         0.14069     0.21249     0.09902    -0.17095
prod.l2      0.06562    -0.02198    -0.08625    -0.02600
rw.l2       -0.05927    -0.06755    -0.05185     0.06046
U.l2         0.39827     0.53742    -0.11558    -0.45224
constant  -136.99845  -166.77552   -33.18834   149.78056
```

I have a few questions though.

1. First of all, how do we interpret these results?
2. What do the coefficients on `e.dl1` , `prod.dl1`, `rw.dl1`, `U.dl1`, `rw.l2`, `U.l2`, `e.l2`, `prod.l2` imply ?
3. How do we relate this to the VECM equation in theory?

$$ \Delta y_t=c+ \Pi y_{t-1}+ \Gamma_1 \Delta y_{t-1}+ ... +\Gamma_{p-1} \Delta y_{t-(p-1)}+\varepsilon_t $$

where $\Pi=\sum A_j -I_k$ and $\Gamma_i=A_j$.

Comment: I corrected your formatting - please check if it is correct. What is your question in here? What is unclear in the output?

Comment: Thank you very much.

so I dont understand what does the coefficients  for e.dl1 , prod.dl1,rw.dl1 stand for ? Are these coefficients in the result  the Π or the Γ? 

What does cajools do ?


Why is there 4 values of the test statistics in the Johansen test ?

Comment: Please edit your question to add those information and describe your question in greater detail.

Comment: Judging on how basic (and also how numerous) your questions are, you may benefit from reading some introductory material such as Pfaff ["Analysis of Integrated and Cointegrated Time Series with R"](http://www.springer.com/us/book/9780387759661) and the ["vars" vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/vars/vignettes/vars.pdf). Then you may come back and ask what is unclear.